# Interaction between jobFinished and onStopJob in JobService

Tags: android, multithreading

**Main question**

Say I have a service derived from `JobService` where I return true in `onStartJob` to indicate I'm having a long running external thread doing the work.

Further say that the system decides to call `onStopJob`.

Now after I have correctly stopped the thread, should `jobFinished` be called or not?

One of these options must be true, but which?

1. `jobFinished` must ALWAYS be called if `onStartJob` returned true no matter if `onStopJob` was called or not
2. `jobFinished` must NOT be called if `onStopJob` was called (maybe there is a risk of a null pointer exception or something?)
3. it doesn't matter if `jobFinished` is called or not if `onStopJob` was called

**Bonus question**

If `onStopJob` is called and returns true to reschedule the job and then once the thread stops `jobFinished` is called with needsRescedule = false (or vice versa), what will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I worked on this JobService and yes its quite confusing API with very less documentation. Below is answer to your queries

- jobFinished must ALWAYS be called if onStartJob returned true no
  matter if onStopJob was called or not - **Answer is NO**
- jobFinished must NOT be called
  if onStopJob was called (maybe there is a risk of a null pointer
  exception or something?) - **Answer is NO**
- it doesn't matter if jobFinished is called 
  or not if onStopJob was called - **Answer below**

Android will keep on retrying your job with your selected RetryStrategy until

- either onStartJob or onStopJob job has returned **false**
- or you
  have called jobFinished with needsReschedule to **false**

[my medium blog here regarding same...](https://medium.com/@akhilgupta.me/android-jobschedulers-cheat-sheet-971049c939d3)